# Find the cluster points for the following

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

Am having problems getting my head around these questions.
I know what cluster points are, but can’t seem to get the question.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: ok sure, am kind of new here

Comment: Welcome to MSE btw.. !

Answer (score 1):

Note that, an accumulation point of a set is a point, every neighborhood of which contains infinitely many points of the set.

(a) clearly set of all accumulation points of $S$ is an closed interval $[\sqrt{2},100]$ (since set $\mathbb{Q}$,  $\mathbb{Q^c}$ are dense in $\mathbb{R}$)

(b) clearly set $S=\{a\in\mathbb{Q}: \sqrt{2}≤a<100\}\cup\{101,102,103,104\}$.

and hence by definition, set of accumulation points of $S$ is the closed interval $[\sqrt{2},100]$ (note that that set integers $\mathbb{Z}$ is closed and hence it has no limit points and hence no accumulation points)

(d) clearly $0$ is accumulation point of the set $S$. Since every neighborhood of $0$ contains infinitely many points of that set and  no other points $p$ in set $S$ is accumulation point(since we can find neighborhood of $p$ that contains no points of $S$)  So here set of accumulation points will be $\{0\}$.

I will leave rest to you, now you have definition and some solved examples.

Comment: thank you so much. I wanted some solved examples and your solution really helped.

Comment: Now i had added (d), and edited my answer.